# How to open the old https message request in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, web-api-testing, scratch-file

I really like the cool feature "stratch file for http request" in PhpStorm. I use it a lot. Each time I ran any GET request, there is a JSON file createed with the result and I can see the file name after the request as follows:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/ping
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

<> 2019-04-16T035128.200.json
<> 2019-04-16T034855.200.json
```

Is there any way I can open the file without executing the http request?

I am using PhpStorm 2019.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of the folder is inside the .idea folder in the project directory. it is a hidden folder and the jsons/files are are stored in the .idea/httprequest folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's a log/result file - you cannot open it without making the call first. If you mean previous files/logs: ctrl+hover mouse over a log file name - it would show you the location of a file. All the previous API call results/logs are stored there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, the ctrl+hover mouseover did not work for me. But I able to locate the location. it is under the .idea/httprequests folder has all this. Thanks for your help